# Sharepoint Admin activity logs

Tags: sharepoint

I need to check all SharePoint Admin activity logs performed at Farm level in SharePoint 2013.
For example activity likes:

- Starting Full synch for user profile
- Starting/stopping any services

Is it possible to do so?

Note: I checked in all logs but did not find any.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013, we do not have a log to record such actions in admin center.